# "Python3 not found" error when deploying docker image to heroku

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, docker, heroku

So I'm trying to deploy my django powered web app to heroku using my docker file, But I keep getting a "python3 not found" error. Note that I've deployed this same application using zeit's now. My dockerfile looks like so:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node

RUN echo "ipv6" >> /etc/modules
RUN echo "http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk add --no-cache python3 yarn && python3 -m ensurepip
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY .  /code
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN yarn
RUN yarn build:dev
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD [python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT ]
```

I've also attached a screenshot of my application's logs on heroku.

[image]

I tried adding the full path to the python3 package like so `/usr/bin/python3` but it still failed. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It actually says `[python3`. Try removing the `[` and `]`. Or use a list like `["python3", "manage.py", ...]`

Comment: I tried the list style, I still go the same error. I'll try without the square brackets

Comment: Removing the square brackets worked